# How Do I Use KeyCloak in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, keycloak

I'm new and I'm building an app and I want to use KeyCloak to auth users. The problem is I've no idea how to do it, and I found a package in the pub.dev package manager but currently it is unable to use in apps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keycloak [supports](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/) [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/), there are multiple packages that helps you implement a OpenID Connect client in flutter. For example:

- [flutter_appauth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth)
- [openid_client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client)

Answer (score 2):

There is a keycloak package as well [keycloak_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/keycloak_flutter/example)

Comment: This Package is his current version 0.0.19 only available for web and like the OP said not for working for apps